# compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints') ERROR

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a problem after adding module Google cloud message. I get this error:

```
Error: Execution failed for task ': app: preDexRelease'.
> Com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process' command 'C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jdk1.8.0_45 \ bin \ java.exe' finished with non zero exit value 1
```

Deleting

> compile project (path ': backend' configuration 'android-endpoints')

everything works perfectly.

What can I do?

Comment: I would not be surprised that you hit 64k limit https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html . Make sure you are not using play-services in build.gradle where a specific service could been used https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: <!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />                                     this may be the problem?

Comment: That is no longer required https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest, you have to provide it only in case of mobile ads https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had both of these dependencies implemented:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'

compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
```

Somehow adding these two together causes the problem and I don't know why. Anyway I added the first dependency so that I can add Ads. I substituted it with:

```
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
```

and the problem is gone.